# Player Doesn't collide with door to enter next level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player to be able to walk to a 2D door, interact with it by pressing the "use" button i've set and load the next level, when the player collides with the blackDoor i made, it doesn't show the text i've set, nor load a level when pressing the use key.

I tried removing the use key entirely, to make both the player and the door collide and just load the level, Didn't work.

I made a java script, didn't work either.
I made an entirely new level, put it on levelToLoad, Didn't work.
I removed the text (To see if it helps) nothing.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OnTriggerEnter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject guiObject;
    public string levelToLoad;
    void Start()
    {
        guiObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            guiObject.SetActive(true);
            if (guiObject.activeInHierarchy == true && Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        guiObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

The player is supposed to just walk regularly to the door, press the use key and load the next level.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 2D Colliders for interaction. Then you're using the wrong function to get callbacks when the Collision or trigger happens.

You're using `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)` instead of `OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)`.

And I also noticed your class name is also `OnTriggerEnter` I don't know if it's allowed to use the Unity Callback function names as class names or not but you might want to change that too.